# C# Use Generics and Expression Trees to get object field values

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I have two classes with similar fields:

```
Class Foo {
    string name;
    int val;
};

Class Bar {
    string name;
    int val;
};
```

Is there a way to use Generics to retrieve the field names and values of objects of these classes? Something along the lines of:

```
string GetName<T> (T obj)
{
    //returns T.name
}
```

I want to make sure there are compile time checks for this, in case the class fields were to change.

Update:

I do not control the definitions of classes Foo and Bar. They will be exposed to me in a library and can change.

I can use something like the following:

```
Type myType = myObject.GetType();
var value = myType.GetProperty("name").GetValue(myObject, null);
```

But I don't think this would check at compile time.

Comment: What's wrong with implementing an Interface?

Comment: As @Areks said use an interface.  Waaay faster than EP too

Comment: I do not control the definition of these classes Foo and Bar. Updated the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want compile-time safety, and you can't modify `Foo` and `Bar`, the typical way to deal with this is with [overloads](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading/):

```
public string GetName(Foo o) { return o.Name; }
public string GetName(Bar o) { return o.Name; }
```

The compiler will automatically pick the method that matches the type of the parameter, so you just need to call it with

```
GetName(eitherObject);
```

...and it's type-safe.

You can't really use generics because Foo and Bar lack a common interface that exposes `Name`.

You can use Reflection, of course, but that means abandoning compile-time safety.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a case where you could use inheritance. If these two classes have similar fields you could make them implement a base class which has all the shared fields. Here is an example:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    int val;
    protected string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name; // Only get is exposed to prevent modifications
        }
    }
}

public class ClassA : BaseEntity
{
   // Other fields or methods
}

public class ClassB : BaseEntity
{
    // Other fields or methods
}
```

Comment: Note your field is protected in the base class thus allowing derived types direct access.   Probably make it private

Comment: @MikyD : I agree with your suggestion. Better to have `get;` autoimplemented property for readability purpose

Comment: This is a metaprogramming question. I do not control the definitions of classes Foo and Bar. These are exposed to me using a library. I have updated the question to reflect this more clearly.